# Finding the height above water level of rocks

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I am currently helping a friend working on a geo-physical project, I'm not by any means a image processing pro, but its fun to play
around with these kinds of problems. =)

The aim is to estimate the height of small rocks sticking out of water, from surface to top.

The experimental equipment will be a ~10MP camera mounted on a distance meter with a built in laser pointer.
The "operator" will point this at a rock, press a trigger which will register a distance along of a photo of the rock, which 
will be in the center of the image.

The eqipment can be assumed to always be held at a fixed distance above the water.

As I see it there are a number of problems to overcome:

1. **Lighting conditions**

   - Depending on the time of day etc., the rock might be brighter then the water or opposite.
   - Sometimes the rock will have a color very close to the water.
   - The position of the shade will move throughout the day.
   - Depending on how rough the water is, there might sometimes be a reflection of the rock in the water.
2. **Diversity**

   - The rock is not evenly shaped.
   - Depending on the rock type, growth of lichen etc., changes the look of the rock.

Fortunateness, there is no shortage of test data. Pictures of rocks in water is easy to come by. Here are some sample images:
[image]
I've run a edge detector on the images, and esp. in the fourth picture the poor contrast makes it hard to see the edges:
[image]
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: They work a bit on the same problem: http://gaugecam.com/blog/?page_id=62 (though I see no solution to your problem)

Comment: It looks like you might be able to tweak your edge detector more http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection

Comment: This is a vision problem; unless you just want help improving the edge detector.

Comment: You have way too many unknowns. You will never robustly measure the height of a rock just given these 2D images. How do you know where the highest point is ? If you had a stereoscopic camera set up plus distance information you could get closer to a real result.

Comment: @svrist - thanks, good resource. Yes you are probably right about the edge detector.

Comment: @koan - Hmm.. By doing the measurments at distance furter away then in these pics, the highest point would probably be more easy to spot... I know its a tricky problem with many unknowns.., but i'd thought I would give it a go anyway =) btw, I added the computer-vision tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that edge detection is best approach to detect the rocks. Other objects, like the mountains or even the reflections in the water will result in edges.

I suggest that you try a pixel classification approach to segment the rocks from the background of the image:

- For each pixel in the image, extract a set of image descriptors from a NxN neighborhood centered at that pixel.
- Select a set of images and manually label the pixels as rock or background.
- Use the labeled pixels and the respective image descriptors to train a classifier (eg. a Naive Bayes classifier)

Since the rocks tends to have similar texture, I would use texture image descriptors to train the classifier. You could try, for example, to extract a few statistical measures from each color chanel (R,G,B) like the mean and standard deviation of the intensity values.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about using a probabilistic classifier, such as the NB, but I cant think how that would eliminate the reflections..

Answer (score 2):

Color segmentation to find the rock, together with edge detection to find the top.

To find the water level I would try and find all the water-rock boundaries, and the horizon (if possible) then fit a plane to the surface of the water.
That way you don't need to worry about reflections of the rock.

Easier if you know the pitch angle between the camera and the water and if the camera is is leveled horizontally (roll).

ps. This is a lot harder than I thought - you don't know the distance to all the rocks so fitting a plane is difficult.

It occurs that the reflection is actually the ideal way of finding the level, look for symetric path edges in the rock edge detection and pick the vertex?

Comment: The rock will be centered in the image, so finding the rock in the image is not a problem. But you where probably referring to extracting the rock from the image. 

Fitting a plane to the water surface make sense, but how do you filter out the reflections?
I agree that the roll and pitch angle should be known, that can easily be accomplished by fitting a simple level like the one you have on camera tripods onto the equipment.

Answer (score 2):

Pixel classification might work here, but will never yield a 100% accuracy. The variance in the data is really big, rocks have different colours (which are also "corrupted" with lighting) and different texture. So, one must account for global information as well.

The problem you deal with is foreground extraction. There are two approaches I am aware of.

1. Energy minimization via graph cuts, see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GrabCut (there are links to the paper and OpenCV implementation). Some initialization ("seeds") should be done (either by a user or by some prior knowledge like the rock is in the center while water is on the periphery). Another variant of input is an approximate bounding rectangle. It is implemented in MS Office 2010 foreground extraction tool. 
   The energy function of possible foreground/background labellings enforces foreground to be similar to the foreground seeds, and a smooth boundary. So, the minimum of the energy corresponds to the good foreground mask. Note that with pixel classification approach one should pre-label a lot of images to learn from, then segmentation is done automatically, while with this approach one should select seeds on each query image (or they are chosen implicitly).
2. [Active contours](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_contour_model) a.k.a. snakes also requre some user interaction. They are more like Photoshop Magic Wand tool. They also try to find a smooth boundary, but do not consider the inner area.

Both methods might have problems with the reflections (pixel classification will definitely have). If it is the case, you may try to find an approximate vertical symmetry, and delete the lower part, if any. You can also ask a user to mark the reflaction as a background while collecting stats for graph cuts.

Comment: Cool, the GrabCut / Graph Cut technique looks really promising. Together with some technique to detect the surface of the water it could it could be interesting. Perhaps you could fit a triangle to the extracted blob, and get an estimate through the triangles height.